# java.lang.SecurityException: JAR manifest requested to run in all-permissons only

Tags: java, security, manifest, java-web-start, manifest.mf

We have a Swing application which downloaded through Java Web Start and runs on local machine. But after automatic launching of the downloaded JNLP file an error occurs:

> Application Blocked by Security Settings Name: Somename Location:
>   http://localhost:8080 The Java security settings have prevented this
>   application from running. You may change this behavior in the Java
>   Control Panel.

This URL already added in exception site list.

Java console doesn't works at that moment, but if launch this JNLP file by command in console:

```
javaws -verbose filename.jnlp
```

we got some exception in trace:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: JAR manifest requested to run in all-permissons only: http://localhost:8080/path/to/jar/jarname.jar
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verify(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verify(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.SandboxSecurity.isPermissionGranted(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResourcesHelper(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Manifest of that Jar file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
version-time: 1926
version-number: 01.030.02.02
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.4
Application-Name: Somename
Permissions: all-permissions
version-date: March 4 2015
Created-By: 1.7.0_75-b13 (Oracle Corporation)
debug: on
Codebase: *
```

Structure of JNLP file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost:8080/" href="/warname/jnlp/filename.jsp">
    <information>
        <title>Title</title>
        <vendor>Company</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://www.foo.com"/>
        <description>Description</description>
        <offline-allowed/>
    </information>
    <resources>

        <j2se max-heap-size="512m" initial-heap-size="128m"
              version="1.3+"/>

        <jar href="/warname/jnlp/lib/jarname.jar"/>
        <jar href="/warname/jnlp/lib/jarname-2.jar" />

        <extension href="/warname/jnlp/help.jsp" name="Java Help"/>
    </resources>
    <application-desc
            main-class="path.to.class.Starter">
        <argument>-java.naming.provider.url=someurl</argument>
        <argument>-java.naming.factory.initial=someinitial</argument>
        <argument>-java.naming.security.principal=login</argument>
        <argument>-java.naming.security.credentials=password</argument>
        <argument>-locatorConfig=server</argument>
        <argument>-verbose</argument>
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Version of Java: 1.7.0_75.

What is the reason of that exception and why app does not start?

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "all-permissions" setting means the application needs to access some of your system resources.

In this case, Oracle says you have to define the same permission both in JNLP and manifest files. You should have a look at the "security" element of JNLP file :

```xml
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>
```

You can find more informations [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/manifest.html).

You may have to change Java security settings. Under Windows you should have an icon on the control panel for Java. Concerning Linux, you can run the "ControlPanel" application inside bin directory of your JDK.

Under the "Security" tab you can add an exception about "localhost". This should help you fix your problem.

Comment: whats the reason to assume the app needs access to environment variables?

Comment: @MarkusKull I misread Oracle's topic. It says about "system resources".

Comment: If i correctly understand your advice, in older version of JNLP file was located strings <security> <all-permissions/> </security>. Result was the same.

Comment: I've added further informations to help you fix your problem.

Comment: @FabienThouraud actually, you was right. After fixing of some problems with java.policy i have added this strings in JNLP file and **in all extensions for that file**. Now app launches without exceptions. Thank you.